# How to add JavaScript chart to HTML document, conditionally?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a function that takes in a number variable and produces a gauge based on the variable.

```
function gaugeProgress(number) {
    percent = number;
    barWidth = 40;
    numSections = 3;
    ...
};
```

This is the original gauge: https://codepen.io/jaketrent/pen/eloGk although a few changes have been made.

I've then got another long function that only occurs once an input is made and a button is clicked.

I originally had the follow if/else statement, to determine if the input matched, and to add a message to the HTML document if it did.

```
 if(x = xyz) {
     addHTML += '<p>blah</p>'
 } else if (x = yz) {
     addHTML += '<p>blah blah</p>';
 else {
     addHTML += '<p>blah blah blah</p>'
 }
```

The if/else statement works as shown above (it does add the HTML line if it matches the user's input).

The gauge also works by itself (if I include `<div class=chart-gauge></div>` in my HTML doc before running.

The issue I'm having is that I can't add the gauge directly from the if/else statement above. I've tried a variety of ways with no luck, such as:

`addHTML += '<div class="chart-gauge">' + gaugeProgress(0.5) + '</div>';`

and

```
addHTML += '<p id="chart-gauge"></p>';
addHTML += document.getElementById("chart-gauge").innerHTML = gaugeProgress(0.5);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have to output the html before calling `innerHTML`! And you try to add a DOM-Object  into `addHTML` as a string ... go for something like `document..id..(id).innerHTML = addHTML` and then perform ur gaugeProgress.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Although I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "output the html before calling innerHTML"? Isn't that what I was doing with `addHTML += '<p id="chart-gauge"></p>';
addHTML += document.getElementById("chart-gauge").innerHTML = gaugeProgress(0.5);`?

Comment: Sorry if its unclear ... you are assigning a string with `'<p id="chart-gauge"></p>'`. So  typeof `addHTML` is a string. Afterwards you try to get the DOM-Object with the id `chart-gauge` which is at the moment - just a string - and assign it with `gaugeProgress`.  [Do something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ccLz8ahz/1/)

Comment: It's not unclear, just my lack of programming knowledge! I understand what you mean now, however, is there a way to do it without adding anything to the html doc initially (so the same as your example but without including `<div id="testx"></div>` in the html doc)?

Comment: Can you post your `gaugeProgress` with your changes on jsFiddle or codepen?

Comment: I've tried it a few different ways, including the ones you suggested, with no luck. It's here: https://jsfiddle.net/nyosvmxy/1/